# Error insert statement PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am having a problem with my database handler class, i think. I have a form tag in my index.php file, which calls a function in inc/function.php, which then saves the form data to a table in the database. The problem is, that i doesnt work, and i cannot find the error. If you want me to provide more information, then please say so :)

There is no error, other than whenever i add the line $dbh->query($sql) in my function, the whole form dissappears :/

index.php:

```
<form id="signform" action="<?php addSignature($dbh) ?>" method="post">
                <h1>SIGN THE PROPOSED CITIZENS’ INITIATIVE</h1>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Full first name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="familynames" placeholder="Family name"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" placeholder="Date of birth"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="placeofbirth" placeholder="Place of birth"><br/>
                <select name="nationality">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Nationality</option>
                    <option value="Denmark" >Denmark</option>
                </select>
                <hr>
                <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address (street, number, other)"></textarea><br/>
                <input type="text" name="postalcode" placeholder="Postal code"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"><br/>
                <select name="country">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
                    <option value="Denmark" >Denmark</option>
                </select>
                <hr>
                <div id="radiobuttons">
                <input class="radiobutton" type="checkbox" name="certify"><span class="radiobuttonText">I hereby certify that the information provided in this 
 form is correct and that I have not already supported 
this proposed citizens’ initiative.</span><br/><br/>
                <input class="radiobutton" type="checkbox" name="privacy"><span class="radiobuttonText">I have read the privacy statement.</span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="">SIGN UP</button>
            </form>
```

DbH.php:

```
<?php

    //DATABASE HANDLER
    class DbH{

        private $connection;
        private $host;
        private $database;
        private $user;
        private $password;
        private $result;

        public function __construct($database, $host='localhost', $user='root', $password='blabla'){
            $this->database = $database;
            $this->host = $host;
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->connect();
        }

        private function connect(){
            try{
                if(!$this->connection = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password)){
                    throw new Exception("No connection to the MySQL server.");
                }
                if(!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connection)){
                    throw new Exception("No connection to the MySQL database.");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        function query($declaration){
            try{
                if(!$this->result=mysql_query($declaration, $this->connection)){
                    throw new Exception("SELECT ERROR</ br>{$declaration}");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        function fetch_array(){
            return $rowArray = @mysql_fetch_array($this->result);
        }

        function getDb(){
            return $this->database;
        }

        function getConnection(){
            return $this->connection;
        }
    }
?>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php

function addSignature($dbh){

if(!isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['familynames'], $_POST['dateofbirth'], $_POST['placeofbirth'], $_POST['nationality'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['postalcode'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['country'])){
    $_POST['firstname'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['familynames'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['dateofbirth'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['placeofbirth'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['nationality'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['address'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['postalcode'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['city'] = 'undefine';
    $_POST['country'] = 'undefine';
}

$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$familynames = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['familynames']);
$dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofbirth']);
$pob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['placeofbirth']);
$nationality = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nationality']);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$postalcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postalcode']);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO signatures (id, firstname, familynames, dob, birthplace, nationality, address, postalcode, city, country)';
$sql .= sprintf(' VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")', $firstname, $familynames, $dob, $pob, $nationality, $address, $postalcode, $city, $country);


$dbh->query($sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? And why are you using this db handler?

Comment: 'I have a in my index.php' a what?, besides, what error are you getting or how do you know its not working?

Comment: I have now edited my question, sorry

Comment: This is *way* too much code, and likely calls for basic debugging first. What goes wrong where? If you simply get a blank screen, you may have error reporting turned off. `mysql_error()` will tell you if anything went wrong with the query

Comment: The fun thing is, that my error reporting is turned on. It's the first time its not giving me any error. I have now reduced the code

Comment: You should consider removing all error suppression operators ('@') from your code, especially while debugging. You may be throwing away useful information.

Comment: An you should reduce your code to the minimum that still produces this error

Comment: i have already done that

Comment: i am using this database handler, because it's a school assignment, where we have to use it. This is not normally the way i do it

Comment: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1409082)

Comment: Even if it was a school assignment, it shouldn't be essential to be done in a specific way. As long as you get the same end result, even if it is half the cod everyone else has, it is still an academic way of doing it.

Comment: have you tried with `display_startup_errors` in php.ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form action should be a page, not a call to a PHP function.

```
<form id="signform" action="<?php addSignature($dbh) ?>" method="post">
```

When you add that line in, you're really calling that function immediately since all PHP code is processed before it outputs to the page, and the action in the source code becomes

```
action=""
```

You need to pass the form either to your same page or to a processing page, which would then pass your POST variables to your addSignature function.

Comment: okay, i will try this and then return!

Comment: so to have a addsignature.php page to parse into the action, would be better? Just to know if i understand you correctly

Comment: But how do i then get access to my $dbh object. Inside the addsignature.php ? :)

Comment: Correct. This way if the page reloads, it won't call the function again. You can just add the $dbh object to the addsignature.php the same way you added it to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `id` field in the `INSERT` statement looks like a auto increment field because in the VALUES part of the INSERT there is no id parameter specified. Or you might need to add an id in the parameters section:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO signatures (firstname, familynames, dob, birthplace, nationality, address, postalcode, city, country)';
$sql .= sprintf(' VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")', $firstname, $familynames, $dob, $pob, $nationality, $address, $postalcode, $city, $country);

$dbh->query($sql);
```

OR

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO signatures (id,firstname, familynames, dob, birthplace, nationality, address, postalcode, city, country)';
$sql .= sprintf(' VALUES ("%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")', $id, $firstname, $familynames, $dob, $pob, $nationality, $address, $postalcode, $city, $country);

$dbh->query($sql);
```

Also ensure that the correct variable types are past to the fields in the table.

Answer (score -2):

I believe there is a syntax error. In your `if` statement you are using commas, but you should be using `&&` or `||`.

Comment: i actually started with using &&, but then PhP gave me an error, telling me to use ,. Im not quite sure why

Comment: He's passing multi arguments to [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), separating them with commas. That is actually valid. Sorry, but your answer is wrong.

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann, that part of your code is correct. This answer is wrong.